# Python NLP differentiation of British English and American English

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, spacy

Currently i am working on a project using nlp and python. i have content and need to find the language. I am using spacy to detect the language. The libraries are providing only language as English language. i need to find whether it is British or American English? Any suggestions?

I tried with Spacy, NLTK, lang-detect. but this libraries provide only English. but i need to display as en-GB for British and en-US for american.

Comment: This question really belongs in Data Science SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can train your own model. Many geographically specific data on English were [collected by University of Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/), but it does not include US English. [American National Corpus](http://www.anc.org) should a free subset that you can use.

A popular library for language *langid.py* allows training your own model. They have a nice [tutorial on github](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py#training-a-model). Their model is based on character tri-gram frequencies, which might not be sufficiently distinctive statistics in this case.

Another option is to train a classifier on top of BERT using e.g., Pytorch and the [transormers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) library. This will surely get very good results, but if you are not experienced with deep learning, it might be actually a lot of work for you.